# Fit different regression models to polynomial data?

Tags: r, model, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am an absolute beginner with R so please bear with me.

I have some generated polynomial (squared) data

```
x.training <- seq(0, 5, by=0.01) # x data
error.training <- rnorm(n=length(x.training), mean=0, sd=1) # Error (0, 1)
y.training <- x.training^2 + error.training  # y data
```

I want to apply 3 different regression models to this data to demonstrate which one has a better fit. My 3 models are linear, polynomial, and trigonometric (cos).

I have tried the following but the lines either don't show up or are just straight lines. How could I go about applying these models properly?

Full code:

```
x.training <- seq(0, 5, by=0.01) # x data
error.training <- rnorm(n=length(x.training), mean=0, sd=1) # Error (0, 1)
y.training <- x.training^2 + error.training  # y data

linear.model <- lm(y.training~x.training)
poly.model <- lm(y.training~poly(x.training, 2))
trig.model <- lm(y.training~cos(x.training))

linear.predict <- predict(linear.model)
poly.predict <- predict(poly.model)
trig.predict <- predict(trig.model)

plot(x.training, y.training)
lines(linear.predict, col="red")
lines(poly.predict, col="blue")
lines(trig.predict, col="green")
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely simple mistake on my part. I feel silly.

```
lines(x.training, linear.predict, col="red")
lines(x.training, poly.predict, col="blue")
lines(x.training, trig.predict, col="green")
```

I wasn't feeding in any X coordinates, and predict only returns Y-hat.

[image: good graph]

Much better!

Comment: be sure to accept your own answer to your question

Comment: @JasonHarrison Can't for another 2 days, thanks for the heads up though. I'll be sure to do that come Friday :)

Comment: Actually for simple typo's like this SO policy is that the question be closed or deleted

Comment: @Hack-R Might have been a typo for someone more experienced :( I was baffled and realized I was wrongly understanding what `predict()` was doing.